# Getting all results from mysql by php

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get MYSQL-informations using *this* code:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE XYZ ");
$res = $db->data();
```

In the database are lots of rows, which result with my query, but in the `$res` variable, I have only one of these.

What do I have to do, to get an array of all results for this code?

Comment: Have you already tried `$res = $db->query("...");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i cannot find the imprtant part wich i do wrong?

Comment: You need to save result from query and do for example a fetch_row to get every row returned from your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * FROM XYZ where XYZ" ) or die(mysqli_error($db));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){

                        while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
                        {                           
                            $details[] =  $data;
                        }

        }
```

what you're doing wrong is there are multiple records in your result & to retrieve them all you needed is loop to fetch every record one by one.
Your approach is right but as you haven't used loop you're getting only one result as data

Hope this helps..

Comment: Don't know for sure,which one is faster but you can try following for speed test   `mysqli_fetch_array()` - Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both
`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` - Fetch a result row as an associative array
`mysqli_fetch_row()` - Get a result row as an enumerated array

Comment: And one another thing you can do is limiting your result by `LIMIT` & fetch next entries by giving `OFFSET` from query